# Electric shower: turning up heat causes low flow cutout

Tags: electrical, plumbing, bathroom, shower, electric-heat

I have an electric shower. It has the usual two dials, one for the heating elements and one for the flow rate.

In summer it works fine, but in winter when the mains water is cold turning up the heat to a satisfactory temperature causes the 'low flow' light to illuminate, turning off the heating elements all together.

I presume the low flow light is coming on to protect the heating elements, but the water is lukewarm when this happens, so is my shower faulty? Is there anything I should check to try and fix it?

Many thanks!

Comment: Colder water takes longer to heat to a specific temperature.  Heating elements are probably not powerful enough to heat the water fast enough.  Maybe a low flow shower head might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to help you without knowing the make/model.

It has a maximum heating capability at given flow rate.

Since the low flow indicator is on it could mean the heating elements are not strong enough or failed.

Incoming water temp is much higher in summer than in winter so the heaters have to work more.

Maybe it is broken or maybe you are already at maximum capacity.

The 3 most common problem are:

It may not be getting hot due to a lack of power caused by damaged fuses or switches, a malfunctioning heating element, or a build-up of solid minerals.

The last one you can solve by removing the build up.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've now taken it apart and it looks like inlet cold water pipe has been "attached" on using bathroom caulk by my landlord (or their contractor), which has caused a leak and killed at least one of the heating elements. As such your answer is right, it was a broken heating element!

Answer (score 1):

### You are overloading it.

The power requirements for an on-demand heater are **flow x rise**.

The rise being the temperature rise you desire vs the input temperature of the water.  For instance if your water arrives at 22°C and you want 40°C, that is a 18°C rise.  If your water arrives at 4°C and you want 40°C, that is a 36°C rise *aka twice as much*.  That, therefore, would require twice as much power for the same flow.  Or, the same power at half the flow.

Note that you get to decide the outlet temperature, but the rise is decided also by the input temperature.

Your unit has a power limit. When the flow x rise that you select exceeds the limit, the unit fails to perform. That is normal and expected. There is nothing wrong with the unit, only your expectations.

### Adjust flow (or temp)

It isn't your fault that inlet temperature is reducing, but you need to account for that **in your CHOICE** of outlet temperature or flow.

I personally would reduce flow since I like a hot shower.

Or, you can choose a more powerful electric shower, call an electrician.

Comment: Thanks - how do I go about reducing flow? If I turn up the "temperature dial" that should reduce flow rate, but doing so causes a "low flow" light to illuminate.

Comment: @Ari Sorry, in your question I thought you said "it has the usual two dials...one for flow" I would expect to be adjusting flow there.  Do you always just set it to maximum? Try not doing that lol.  I would be very surprised if it could automatically adjust flow for you, that sounds hard/expensive (it would need to be servo-motors operating the flow dial, it can't electrically regulate flow without very expensive kit).  If you can't adjust flow, you'll need to add a flow restrictor at the shower head, or a lower flow showerhead.

Comment: My understanding is that the way that electric showers actually adjust the temperature of the water coming out of the head is by adjusting the flow rate through the heating elements so that the water spends longer in contact with them. Having now taken my shower apart I can see that it's been installed by a madman with a caulk gun, so am consigning it to the skip and will replace it. Thanks for your help though!